# requestWhenInUseAuthorization error on IOS 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, geolocation, maps

I'm using the last Xcode version to developp an app which handles geolocalisation.
I use this line of code and already added the description in my plist file :

```
[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

This works perfectly on iOS 8 but still not working on iOS 7.
How can I handle geolocalisation (prompting user and update it's location) on both iOS 7 and 8 versions ?

EDIT

On Xcode 6 my base SDK is iOS 8 and my deployment target is 7.0 and more (here the code works fine).
If I want to launch the simulator on previous version such as 7.0 I need to launch the project with Xcode 5. That's where I get the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my app I wrote something like this:

```
self.locationManager                 = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8)
{
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
self.locationManager.delegate        = self;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

And it's perfectly working for me.

**EDIT:**

You don't need xcode 5 for running app on iOS 7. You can install iOS 7 simulator for Xcode 6.

Go to Xcode preferences, under downloads download iOS 7 simulator.

[image: Preference Menu]

[image: Download]

Comment: Seems like the requestWhenInUseAuthorization doesn't exist under Xcode 5 with the iOS 7.1. I get the "no visible interface" message :/ and can't launch the App on the simulator.

Comment: @SuperGuillaume Yes, it won't work in XCode 5 and iOS 7. It's introduced in iOS 8 and XCode 6

Comment: Is there any way to make this work on both version ?

Comment: @SuperGuillaume: I'm using the above code and it is working in both version. I have an application in AppStore which uses the same code and works fine

Comment: Despite the fact I have errors with the simulator on iOS 7, you mean that it will work on real devices with iOS 7 ?

Comment: Set your base SDK as IOS 8. Deployment target as 7.0 or above. Then check is there any error or not

Comment: You don't need xcode 5 for running app on iOS 7. You can install iOS 7 simulator for Xcode 6. Go to Xcode preferences, under downloads download iOS 7 simulator

Comment: Never saw these downloads links until I downloaded Xcode 5. Thanks I will try to debug using Xcode 6 on iOS 7 simulator :)